# Create ClientContext using current user in C#

Tags: sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

I'm trying to create a ClientContext using the current user. I've tried many ways but all of which only work when I run on localhost. When I push the code to the server, it doesn't work anymore. Please help.

I've tried the following:

```
ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextWithWindowsIdentity(myUri, HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity)
```

or

```
Web web = clientContext.Web;
clientContext.Load(web);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

clientContext.Load(web.CurrentUser);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

or

```
ICredentials credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
NetworkCredential credential = credentials.GetCredential(myUri, "NTLM");
clientContext.Credentials = credential;
```

Comment: Are you writing a provider hosted app or a client application that connects to SharePoint?

Comment: Yes, im writing a provider hosted app.

Comment: @SebastianSchütze: If I am writing a client application or stand alone application that should connect to the sharepoint. Will the same steps be followed for creating the client context for the current logged in user

Answer (score 1):

it is important to have a properly configured high-trust

so

## 1. Check high-trust for access provider hosted apps

- [How to: Create high-trust apps for SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179901(v=office.15).aspx)
- Deploy app manifest for target server or manualy change manifest content (*.app file = zip package)
- **IssuerID** in web.config and SP are identical
- **ClientId** in web.config and app manifest are indetical
- **ClientSigningCertificatePath** and **ClientSigningCertificatePassword** are correct

## 2. Simple Code

```
var hostUri = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);
var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextWithWindowsIdentity(hostUri, HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity);
clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, w => w.Title);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
Response.Write(clientContext.Web.Title);
```

## 3. Your app has access to SP

- Check page "Site app permissions" (.../_layouts/15/appprincipals.aspx?Scope=Web)

## 4. Your account has access to SP

- For completeness

Comment: If I am writing a client application or stand alone application that should connect to the sharepoint. Will the same steps be followed for creating the client context for the current logged in user